# Website gives blank screen after facebook connect login

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, fbconnect

I use facebook connect for users to login and register on my website. But strangely, after authentication from facebook and after the login pop closes, my website throws me a blank screen, on Chrome. However, on FF I am getting a message of redirect loop error. Any idea why this is happening? Please do not reply by telling check app settings. I am pretty sure they are correct.
The FB settings are:
Site URL: http://carbonerroworld.com/
Site Domain: carbonerroworld.com

Comment: Are you sure you're catching the message back from Facebook (and interpreting it accordingly)? It sounds like Facebook sends back its token, then you're going back to Facebook to obtain a token, and so on and so forth.

Comment: yes, yes. all that happens fine. I am able to get the user details logged into my database, but I get a blank screen on the site

Comment: what is your `redirect_uri` in the login url? (BTW - chances are that is **IS** a problem with your settings...)

Comment: It is the domain name to which I want the user to be redirected. http://carbonerroworld.com is the site btw

Comment: Update: If I login with the account that has registered the app on Facebook I am having no issues in loggin in and signing up. Everything works fine. From any other id, I am getting blank screen.

Comment: Are you using the PHP library?

Comment: Yes, I am using the PHP library